# What do I do if Arvak's skull isn't where its supposed to be?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to get Arvak's skull so I can get the horse.

But his skull isn't where it's supposed to be... It should be at the boneyard, on the pedestal, but for some reason it's not.

How can I get the skull?

Comment: That depends. What platform are you playing on? On the PC, you should be able to use a console command to make it appear. I don't see any related bugs listed on either of the pages for [Arvak's Skull](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arvak's_Skull) or [Find Arvak's Skull](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Find_Arvak%27s_Skull). Did you talk to the soul of his owner?

Answer (score 2):

It might just be invisible, if not try looking around(you might have used unrelenting force shout in the fight next to it).